# Displaying user uploaded videos using YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api

I'd like to create a website that allows users to upload video to a YouTube channel and also embeds those YouTube videos into my website. Is this possible using YouTube's API? How would I go about learning how to do this? I am familiar with HTML5/CSS3 and Python and am acquainted with Java and JavaScript.  Any advice is very appreciated.

Comment: Here are some relevant docs you can check out: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video, https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try ?
[YouTube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/)

YouTube API has python API that allow you to use YouTube at your site

Answer (score 0):

Below is sample page using JavaScript to invoke the YouTube Player to play video embedded in a web page. The sample shows how to play just one video and how to queue several videos and then play them. The sample plays a default video automatically when the page is loaded. When a video is finished playing, the default video is played.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Play YouTube Videos</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tag = document.createElement('script');
tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/player_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);
var player;
var videosQueuedCount;
function onYouTubePlayerAPIReady() {
videosQueuedCount = 1;
var vars = {
   autoplay: 1,
   enablejsapi: 1,
   controls: 1
}
player = new YT.Player('ytplayer', {
   height: '390',
   width: '640',
   playerVars: vars,
   videoId:'HL6ZL9q3UJ8',
   events: {
      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
 });
}
function onPlayerReady(evt) {
}
function playVideo(VID) {
  window.top.scrollTo(0,200);
  videosQueuedCount = 1;
  player.loadVideoById(VID);
}
function queueVideo(queuedCount,VID) {
  window.top.scrollTo(0,200);
  videosQueuedCount = queuedCount;
  player.loadPlaylist(VID);
  player.playVideo();
}
function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
  if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.ENDED) {
    videosQueuedCount -= 1;
    if (videosQueuedCount < 1) {
      videosQueuedCount = 1;
      playVideo('HL6ZL9q3UJ8');
    }
  }
}
</script>
<div id="ytplayer"></div>
<p><b>10/22/2015</b> <a href="javascript:playVideo('kaLlstcp5GE');">East Lyme, CT Issues and Answers (28:26)</a><br>
Information<br>Teri Smith of Smith&#39;s Acres and Niantic Main Street<br>
</p>
<p><b>10/21/2015 East Lyme, CT Board of Selectmen Meeting</b><br>
Regular Meeting<br>
<a href="javascript:playVideo('naz9POIJvwI');">Part 1 (28:50)</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:playVideo('q3p1eexyUxY');">Part 2 (29:25)</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:playVideo('R17mYVS4ZMg');">Part 3 (29:17)</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:playVideo('jDiaFwVfHWg');">Part 4 (01:53)</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a href="javascript:queueVideo(4,['naz9POIJvwI','q3p1eexyUxY','R17mYVS4ZMg','jDiaFwVfHWg']);">All</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps!